# Dynamically change a static resource

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my App.xaml I have two resources

```
<x:Double x:Key="MasterGridSize">150</x:Double>
<DataTemplate x:Key="MasterGridItemTemplate">
   <Grid Width="{StaticResource MasterGridSize}" Height="{StaticResource MasterGridSize}">
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I change the value of `MasterGridSize` it does not change the grid size - as expected. How can I achieve this?

I tried `ThemeResource`, then it's at least changing, when the theme changes.

`DynamicResource` is not available.

I don't want to add MasterGridSize to the ViewModel, since this would lead to some dependencies between ViewModels and some update code.

Any other ideas?

Edit: It might also be reasonable to edit the DataTemplate directly - how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a value holder, like the [BindableValueHolder](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/BindableValueHolder/) from the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit).

```
<helpers:BindableValueHolder x:Key="MasterGridSize">
    <helpers:BindableValueHolder.Value>
        <x:Double>150</x:Double>
    </helpers:BindableValueHolder.Value>
</helpers:BindableValueHolder>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MasterGridItemTemplate">
    <Grid Width="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource MasterGridSize}}" Height="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource MasterGridSize}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Source code available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Helpers/BindableValueHolder.cs)!

Comment: Thank you. I missed the `Source={Statice...` part. Also I did not know about the BindableValueHolder (which I tried to implement by myself). Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your resources very well? If yes, try GridLength as follows:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <GridLength x:Key="FirstSize">5*</GridLength>
    <GridLength x:Key="SecondSize">4*</GridLength>
</Page.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MasterGridItemTemplate">
  <Grid Width="{StaticResource FirstSize}" Height="{StaticResource SecondSize}">
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Grid.Width/Height needs to be double - which leads to an exception